# How to create setup application

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio

I want to make "Set Up" project [like in this video tutorial](https://youtu.be/ZxMMJHn_AtQ?t=44), but I can not find the "Set Up" project in Visual Studio (2017).

What do I need to install so I can create a "Set up Project" from `New → Project`?

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvEWp.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio dropped shipping Setup project, at least it was the case for VS 2015. There is an [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects) that brings the experience back, I didn't try it though.

You can use [ViX](http://wixtoolset.org/) too, it is free,open souce and powerful but it demands some time and energy to learn.

Answer (score 0):

VS 2008 was the last which included Setup projects. At my former job we used [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php).